# React Application does not display data fetched from MongoDB Atlas

Tags: reactjs, axios, mern, react-context, mongodb-atlas

I'm creating a simple web application (MERN stack) that fetches data from MongoDb Atlas. I have two components one is called Listings (an array of listing Items) and the other one is called ListingItem:

The Listings.js component:

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext, useEffect } from "react";

import ListingItem from "./ListingItem";
import ListingContext from "../../context/listing/listingContext";

const Listings = () => {
 const listingContext = useContext(ListingContext);

 const { listings, getListings, loading } = listingContext;

 useEffect(() => {
 getListings();
 // eslint-disable-next-line
 }, []);

 return (
 <Fragment>
   {listings.map((listing) => (
     <ListingItem key={listing._id} listing={listing} />
   ))}
 </Fragment>
 );
 };

export default Listings;
```

The ListingItem.js component:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import ShareIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Share";

import listingImage from "../../resources/listing.jpg";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
 root: {
  maxWidth: 345,
 },
 media: {
  height: 0,
  paddingTop: "56.25%", // 16:9
 },
 avatar: {
  backgroundColor: "coral",
 },
}));

const ListingItem = (listing) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const { neighbourhood, bedrooms, price, priceCurr, area, areaUoM } = listing;

  return (
   <div className="container">
    <div className="listing-item">
    
     <Card className={classes.root}>
       <CardHeader
         avatar={<Avatar className={classes.avatar} />}
         title="Title"
         subheader="Subtitle"
       />
       <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={listingImage} title="" />
       <CardContent>
        
        <Typography component="p">
          {price} {priceCurr}
        </Typography>
        <Typography component="p">A {bedrooms} bedroom,</Typography>
        <Typography component="p">
          {area} {areaUoM} apartment
        </Typography>
        <Typography component="p">Located in {neighbourhood}</Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing>
        <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
          <FavoriteIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton aria-label="share">
          <ShareIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  </div>
</div>
);
};

ListingItem.propTypes = {
 listing: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default ListingItem;
```

The App is obviously connected to the Mongodb Atlas, because when I run the app, it renders exactly two Listing Items to the screen (I have two documents in the database). But it does not display the variables  {price}, {priceCurr}, {bedrooms} and {neighbourhood} which I have in ListingItem Component.

Is there anybody who has experienced the same issue?

Comment: In `ListingItem` can you console.log a for example `priceCurr`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It returns undefined for all the four variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to display the data present in **listings**.
First of all console it before returning the **listings** to **ListingItem** and if it do not contains any data then there might be different object structure or might be empty.

After it really contains the data then try this:

```
 const Listings = () => {
 const listingContext = useContext(ListingContext);

 const { listings, getListings, loading } = listingContext;

 useEffect(() => {
 getListings();
 // eslint-disable-next-line
 }, []);

 return (
 <Fragment>  //Try passing whole object of **listings**
     <ListingItem key={listing._id} listing={listings} />
 </Fragment>
 );
 };

export default Listings;
```

After that in **ListingItem** Component try this:

```
    const ListingItem = (props) => {
      const classes = useStyles();
        
      return (
        
       props && props.listing.map(item=>{ //Apply map after checking props
        <div className="container">
        <div className="listing-item">
        
         <Card className={classes.root}>
           <CardHeader
             avatar={<Avatar className={classes.avatar} />}
             title="Title"
             subheader="Subtitle"
           />
           <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={listingImage} title="" />
           <CardContent>
            
            <Typography component="p">
              {item.price} {item.priceCurr}
            </Typography>
            <Typography component="p">A {item.bedrooms} bedroom,</Typography>
            <Typography component="p">
              {item.area} {item.areaUoM} apartment
            </Typography>
            <Typography component="p">Located in {item.neighbourhood}</Typography>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions disableSpacing>
            <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
              <FavoriteIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton aria-label="share">
              <ShareIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </div>
     }) 
    );
    };
```

**Second way is to access it after destructuring of props**

So, In your **ListingItem Component** access **listing** like this:

```
const {neighbourhood, bedrooms, price, priceCurr, area, areaUoM }= listing.listing;
```

And it will access it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have done wrong destructuring of props.

```
<ListingItem key={listing._id} listing={listing} />

const ListingItem = ({listing}) => {
```

Wrap your props inside a `{}`